# Probing and Analyzing MIPI CSI 2 Interface

Tags: camera, csi

I'm looking at probing and analyzing the MIPI CSI 2 interface on D-Phy with a Keysight 16802A 68-channel logical analyzer plus the N4851A/B probe.

The question is, usually a 16802A can have different memory depth, from 1M to 32M. If the image being analyzed is a 4-k image, in 12bit raw format, how much memory would be required on 16802A?

As a side question, does anybody have other approaches to probe and analyze the interface with a simpler equipment?

Answer (score 1):

I am not at all sure that the 16802A goes fast enough for 4k, and it certainly will not have sufficient memory to capture a whole frame in timing mode.

Mind you, usually a logic analyser has very sophisticated trigger setup, so you should be able to capture just the transaction you are interested in, there is probably no need to try to capture the whole frame.

The real answer as always depends on exactly what you are trying to see.